# Quarkus - Panache how to execute a custom query

Tags: mysql, crud, quarkus, quarkus-panache

In spring, we can declare a custom query like this

```java
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.status = 1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsersNative();
```

but in Quarkus I cannot find a reference on how to do this in quarkus

Does anyone have any experience with how to do this?

Comment: You can use extension for spring data api (https://quarkus.io/guides/spring-data-jpa#supported-spring-data-jpa-functionalities)

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/36168

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this in your User entity (which should extend PanacheEntity) :

```java
public static List<User> findByStatus() {
   return list("status=1");
}
```

See also documentation:
https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#adding-entity-methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your custom queries as NamedQuery.
See: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#named-queries

In your scenario, it could look like this:

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "custom.allActiveUsers", query = "FROM USERS u WHERE u.status = 1")
})
public class User extends PanacheEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "version")
    public Long version;
    
    public static List<User> getActiveUsers() {
        return find("#custom.allActiveUsers");
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are extending PanacheEntity, then using NamedQueries doesn't make sense.